Unable to attach volume attach to EC2 instance using Cloudformation
I created a template in which I have an EC2 instance and a volume in the same template. I want to attach the volume to the EC2 instance, but I get a "volume does not exist" error even though I used the DependsOn attribute.
  VolumeAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
    DependsOn: PowerBIDesktopVolumeAttach
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2Instance
      VolumeId: !Ref VolumeAttach
      Device: "xvdb"


Can you show us the rest of your Cloudformation template? You refer to PowerBIDesktopVolumeAttach in the DependsOn parameter, but to VolumeAttach in the VolumeId paramater. Are they two different volumes?
